# tvOS UITableView black background

Tags: uitableview, tvos

After moving to Xcode 12, my tvOS app now has black backgrounds in all the UITableViews. This happens on a real device (newest Apple TV 4K) as well as in the simulator.

In the Xcode project, all the default settings are used for the UITableView so it should have a transparent background and take on the look of the view it is contained in.

When using a Light appearance, the background is white but should be transparent.

What has happened in the transition from Xcode 11 to Xcode 12?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you must now explicitly set the background color to clear.